# How to only show logged in user's posts to user?

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a site where the user will only be able to see their own posts.

Note: I am not talking about the admin section. I want to limit the posts that are displayed on the public facing site to only show posts that belong to that logged in user.

If they are not logged in they will see the pages but no posts. If they are logged in but don't have any posts the pages will be blank as well. But if they are logged in an have created posts those posts will be visible on the relevant pages.

Is this possible? Already a feature of wp but I haven't seen it yet?

Answer (score 1):

Use [custom query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) in your template

```
$current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'author' => $current_user_id ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get logged user's posts with this code below.

```
<?php 

$user = wp_get_current_user();
$usatual = $user->user_login;
$usemail = $user->user_email;
echo 'Posts from user:'.$usatual.', e-mail: '.$usemail.'<BR><BR>';

$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'author' => $user->ID,
);
$query = new WP_Query($query_args);
echo '<table><tr>';
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        $post = $query->post;
        $title = $post->post_title;
        $content = $post->post_content;
        echo '<tr><td>' . $title . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $content . '</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</tr></table>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
else{
    echo 'No posts found.';
}

?>
```